# TypeScript error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts

Tags: typescript

Why do I receive an error for the same code from TS tutorial that doesn't throw errors?

From tutorial (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespacing):

1. namespace.
2. interface within namespace
3. class implements interface
4. class implements method

```js
namespace Validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }

    const lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    const numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;

    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }

    export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

My almost identical code that throws.

1. namespace.
2. interface within namespace
3. class implements interface
4. class implements method

```js
// index.d.ts

declare namespace LA {
  export interface BelAir {
    populate(): undefined;
  }

  interface Burbank {

  }

  export class BelAirClass implements BelAir {
    populate() {  // Error is thrown here, 
      return undefined
    }
  }

}

// la.ts
import LA from './index';

const ba = new LA.BelAirClass();
const u: undefined = ba.populate();

console.log('[ba]', ba);
console.log('[u]', u);

// CLI
$ npm run tsc la.ts

index.d.ts:11:16 - error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses `declare nampespace`, this is used to write declarations (for existing JS code usually) without any implementation. Also your code is in a `d.ts` file which are again used for writing declarations for existing JS code. If you remove the `declare` and move the code to a `.ts` file it will work. Also add an `export` if you want to `import` the namespace in another file:

```
// index.ts
export namespace LA {
  export interface BelAir {
    populate(): undefined;
  }

  interface Burbank {

  }

  export class BelAirClass implements BelAir {
    populate() {  // Error is thrown here, 
      return undefined
    }
  }

}

// la.ts
import { LA } from './index';

const ba = new LA.BelAirClass();
const u: undefined = ba.populate();

console.log('[ba]', ba);
console.log('[u]', u);
```

Also since you are using modules (ie the `export` and `import` syntax) using `namespace` is not advisable and is actually bad practice. See [GH comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30994#issuecomment-492024848):

> It comes down to this:
>   If you're considering using namespaces for code organization: Don't. Modules have subsumed that role.
>   If you need functionality that only namespaces can provide: Do, but check that it's not equally expressive to express the concept without a namespace (eg, with a class static or function property, or reexported module). It is also bad style to mix namespaces and modules in the same project - it just feels off, since one of the major features of namespaces in the traditional sense is cross-file scope merging, which doesn't occur across modules (since, as I said, the module itself is actually a namespace).

So your code with modules would be:

```
// index.ts


export interface BelAir {
  populate(): undefined;
}

interface Burbank {

}

export class BelAirClass implements BelAir {
  populate() {  // Error is thrown here, 
    return undefined
  }
}



// la.ts
import * as LA from './index';

const ba = new LA.BelAirClass();
const u: undefined = ba.populate();

console.log('[ba]', ba);
console.log('[u]', u);
```